# Navigate between two router outlets

Tags: angular-router, router-outlet

I would like to navigate between two outlets in my Angular application.

First of all, my first view: `app.html`:

```
<div class="app">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

  <router-outlet name="application"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Then, my `application.html` template, which is a wrapper for some children states:

```
<div>
   <some-navbar></some-navbar>
   <div class="application__router-wrapper">
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </div>
</div>
```

And my routes definitions:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: { state: 'LOGIN' }
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: { state: 'REGISTER' }
  }
  },
  {
    path: 'application',
    component: ApplicationComponent,
    outlet: 'application',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'notes',
        component: NotesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'reminders',
        component: RemindersComponent
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

My login function which does redirection:

```
login() {
  this.router.navigate(['/application/notes']);
}
```

So what is my problem: I can easily naviage between login and register view (I use one component for these two views), but I can't get to application/notes. I am getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'application/notes'
```

So what am I doing wrong? Where's the mistake in my code?

Comment: I think you should approach lazy loading. make separate module for application routes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { application: ['application', 'notes'] } }]);

// or (I'm not sure which one)

this.router.navigate(['', { outlets: { application: ['notes'] } }]);
```

Comment: I tried the first version, and my URL looks like this: http://localhost:4200/login(application:application/notes). Second version doesn't work.